# Typescript error "Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression" in Vuex module

Tags: typescript, vue.js, module, vuex

I have the following Vuex module using Typescript that I'm exporting from a library:

```
import * as types from '@/store/types';
import {Formio} from 'formiojs';
import { VuexModule, Module, Mutation, Action } from 'vuex-module-decorators'

interface RoleItem {
  _id: string;
  title: String;
  admin: Boolean;
  default: Boolean;
}

interface RoleList {
  [key: string]: RoleItem;
}

export class Auth extends VuexModule {
  public user: {}
  public loggedIn: boolean
  public roles: {}
  public forms: {}
  public userRoles: {}

  @Action
  setUser({ state, commit, dispatch }, user) {
    commit(types.SET_USER, user);
    dispatch('setLoggedIn', true);
    dispatch('setUserRoles', state.roles);
  }
  @Action
  setLoggedIn({commit}, loggedIn) {
    commit(types.SET_LOGGED_IN, loggedIn);
  }
  @Action
  getAccess({ commit, dispatch, getters }) {
    const projectUrl = Formio.getProjectUrl();
    Formio.request(projectUrl + '/access')
      .then(function(accessItems) {
        commit(types.SET_ROLES, accessItems.roles);
        commit(types.SET_FORMS, accessItems.forms);
        if (getters.getLoggedIn) {
          dispatch('setUserRoles', accessItems.roles);
        }
    });
  }
  @Action
  setUserRoles({ commit, getters }, roles: RoleList) {
    const roleEntries = Object.entries(roles);
    const userRoles = getters.getUser.roles;
    const newRolesObj = {};
    roleEntries.forEach((role) => {
      const roleData = role[1];
      const key = 'is' + role[1].title.replace(/\s/g, '');
      newRolesObj[key] = !!userRoles.some(ur => roleData._id === ur);
    });
    commit(types.SET_USER_ROLES, newRolesObj);
  }

  @Mutation
  [types.SET_USER](user) {
    this.user = user;
  }
  @Mutation
  [types.SET_LOGGED_IN](loggedIn: boolean) {
    this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
  }
  @Mutation
  [types.SET_ROLES](roles: RoleList) {
    this.roles = roles;
  }
  @Mutation
  [types.SET_FORMS](forms) {
    this.forms = forms;
  }
  @Mutation
  [types.SET_USER_ROLES](userRoles) {
    this.userRoles = userRoles;
  }
}

export default Auth;
```

I want to simply import it it in the parent vue app as a namespaced Vuex module and add it to my store as a new module:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import { Auth } from 'vue-formio'

Vue.use(Vuex);

...

resourceModules.auth = Auth;

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: resourceModules,
  strict: debug,
});
```

That part all works fine. The problem is setting the `namespaced: true` and `name :auth` properties in the exported store. From what I've [read](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-write-a-vue-js-app-completely-in-typescript/), I should be able to do it with the `@Module` decorator like this:

```
@Module({ namespaced: true, name: 'auth' })
export class Auth extends VuexModule {
```

However, as soon as I add the parentheses after the `@Module` decorator, I get this TS error in my IDE:

> TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression. Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'void' has no compatible call signatures.

As seen in the [vuex-module-decorators](https://github.com/championswimmer/vuex-module-decorators/blob/635e8aac4ef7c396333c97c0519d841333ef1824/src/moduleoptions.ts#L5-L18) code, these are allowed options:

```
export interface StaticModuleOptions {
  /**
   * name of module, if being namespaced
   */
  name?: string;
  /**
   * whether or not the module is namespaced
   */
  namespaced?: boolean;
  /**
   * Whether to generate a plain state object, or a state factory for the module
   */
  stateFactory?: boolean;
}
```

This is my first foray into Typescript, so I'm stumped. I'm still researching, but in the meantime, how do I add the namespacing to this Vuex module with Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

A quickfix I figured out is to add

> import { ModuleOptions } from 'vuex-module-decorators/dist/types/moduleoptions';
>
> @Module({
> dynamic: true,
> name: 'user',
> namespaced: true,
> store: Store
> } as ModuleOptions)

to the configuration object.